# Drag&Drop files from JList to windows explorer not working out of JAR/EXE

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist, file-transfer

I have a `JList` with Drag&Drop enabled. Now I add files from a package in my Java project to the `JList` a let them display with it's icon in front. Now if I D&D from the `JList` to the desktop, it works great, but if I create a `JAR` file (or an EXE file using `launch4j`) Drag&Drop of the files in the JAR doesn't work anymore. Any solutions? Here is my `Transferable` and `TransferHandler` class which is set to the JList:

```
public class TransferableFile implements Transferable
{
  private List<File> fileList;

  public TransferableFile(List<File> files)
  {
    fileList = files;
  }

  @Override
  public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
  {
    return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
  {
    return flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
  {
    if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
      return fileList;

    throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
  }
}




public class FileListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler
{
  @Override
  public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
  {
    return COPY;
  }

  @Override
  protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    JList<File> list = (JList<File>) c;
    File value = (File) list.getSelectedValue();
    Vector<File> files = new Vector<>();
    String listEntry;
    listEntry = value.getAbsolutePath();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, listEntry);
    files.add(new File(listEntry));
    TransferableFile tf = new TransferableFile(files);
    return tf;
  }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And along with your SSCCE, you should say what happens instead of the behavior you expect.

Comment: Okay, there is nothing happenin. No copying of the document out of the JList to the explorer. While starting in Ecipse, it works great. Out of JAR/EXE-File not.